# Strange output of git branch

Tags: git

I have really strange output of "git branch". I type git branch in terminal and instead of getting the output of all branches in the terminal, I get the output in some file with the name of all branches opens and with "END" word in the end of this file. To exit I have to press q. How can I get the standard output of this command directly in the terminal?

Comment: That's not strange. I think it's a program called `less`. it's the standard output for a lot of programs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following command to get a list of branches printed to your terminal

```sh
git branch --list | cat
```